# do_action inside class issue with add_meta_boxes hook

Tags: php, wordpress, class

Ok, this is a little specific. I might be missing something but since it killed me enough time , even though I found a way around it, I need to know if there's a way to do it properly.

Basically I want to use add_meta_box (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box ) inside a class.

What I am doing:

```
//an array variable I am trying to pass in the class to a callback function as a parameter
$the_array = array(
    'something',
    'my meta box'
);
//a class where everything happens
class some_class {
//public function that has the array and initiates the add_meta_boxes hook
    public function add_box($class_array) {
        //add meta boxes hook to add the meta box properly
        add_action('add_meta_boxes', array($this, 'adding_custom_meta_boxes'), 10, 2);
        //passing the array variable to the callback function
        do_action('add_meta_boxes',$class_array);
    }
//the callback function of the add_meta_boxes hook
    public function adding_custom_meta_boxes($class_array) {
        add_meta_box('my-meta-box', __($class_array[1]), 'render_my_meta_box', 'page', 'normal', 'default');
    }
    public function render_my_meta_box(){
        //the code to generate the html of the meta box goes here
    }

}

$class_var = new some_class();
$class_var->add_box($the_array);
```

I get this error:
Fatal error: Call to undefined function add_meta_box() in C:\xampp\ht.....

but only if I use do_action to pass the variables to the hook callback function

I found a way around it with global variables, but , does anybody know a correct way of doing this?

I am trying to create the meta box from inside a class and this happens. It works well from outside a class. Anybody any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

your not too far off. to correct the above change to this:

```
public function adding_custom_meta_boxes($class_array) {
    add_meta_box('my-meta-box', __($class_array[1]), array($this, 'render_my_meta_box'), 'page', 'normal', 'default');
}
```

- remove "do_action"

do_action tells the script to perform the attached actions right now and the function add_meta_boxes has yet to load (google the load process for wp functions). Thats the whole point of add_actions / Filters!

Comment: Ok, removing do_action solves the problem( no more error) sure, but how do I pass the array parameter to the do_action hook without do_action?

Comment: The actual problem is passing the variable to the hook inside the class. Using do_action solves that problem but it only works outside the class. So, the problem remains. Anybody have any more ideas?

Comment: hmm not sure your grasping this, you are adding the action with add_action, this will run the function attached to this and the add_meta_box function now and the callback to create the box. The array variable[1] is a name only , put in bob it will also work..do you not see the box created when you remove do action?

Comment: A right i see what you mean, The array is not available to your script within the class. This is a feature of OOP. You can define it as a variable belonging to the script or as you are doing use globals. But why not define the array within your class?

Comment: I am creating the class to make meta boxes from an outside array. I am using the first function (add_box) in the example above to send the array to the class and then I manage it globally trough the class. That is my workaround. Was looking for another way...

Comment: well if you really wanted to not use globals or database you could wrap the array in a class and initialize within the new class..but i think unless you have a extremely cluttered global space or want to extend your code indefinitely you are using the best option.